# How can I add a badge in output message command of laravel artisan?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-10

I am creating a laravel artisan command and work fine, but I want the output like the bellow image
someone know the solution for this question?
[laravel artisan command output sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWkt3.png)

I want add a  badge like a native artisan command.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't in the documentation, but the way the base Artisan commands do this is via `$this->components->info(...)`. This seems to work in a generated Console Command, via `extends Command`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class ExampleCommand extends Command {
  protected $signature = 'example';

  public function handle() {
    $this->components->info('Hello World.');
  } 
}
```

Running this command via `php artisan example` generates the following output:

> INFO Hello World.

Screenshot:

[image]

Example in the Framework Codebase:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Console/GeneratorCommand.php#L194